Configuring Cypress Snapshots for Cross-Device Consistency
We're newly integrating Cypress into our project for component testing and have also integrated a snapshot testing plugin for our UI components. However, when I run snapshot testing, it's failing even though the snapshots appear visually identical.
I suspect this might be due to the DPI (Dots Per Inch) settings being different between the devices where the initial snapshots were taken and where the tests are currently running.
What configuration settings can we adjust in Cypress to ensure snapshots are taken that are identical across all devices?
command.ts file:
import { addMatchImageSnapshotCommand } from 'cypress-image-snapshot/command;

addMatchImageSnapshotCommand({
  failureThreshold: 0.0,
  failureThresholdType: 'percent',
});

cypress.config file:
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import { addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin } from 'cypress-image-snapshot/plugin';

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: 'react',
      bundler: 'webpack',
    },
    setupNodeEvents(on) {
      addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin(on);
    },
  },
});

snapshot taken by
cy.matchImageSnapshot(image-name)


Could you increase the failureThreshold value?

This is a fairly classic annoying problem, and yes its OS differences. The only real answer I've found for this (threshold tweak is unreliable for many cases, and case specific) is to execute the Cypress tests inside of docker both locally in CI, to normalise the base OS. And then add entry points/parameterise the docker file to be able to get new snapshots back out of the container.
